# When Message is sent from SfB client to bot, It receives two responses. Address-Id with "sip" and without "sip"

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

**Bot Info**

- SDK Platform: Node.js
- Botbuilder Version: 3.8.4
- Active Channels: Skype for Bussiness
- Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service, Azure App Service

**Issue Description**

On chat initiation from users to bot using Skype for Business clients like Android, iOS, and Mac, bot receives two responses (type: message) from users.

But while using Windows SFB client, bot receives only 1 response.

This happens only for first message (during chat initiation): address -Id in the first message Json is withoud `sip` and second message is with `sip`.

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

//
//other Code
//

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog()
    .onDefault((session) => {        
        session.send('Sorry, I did not understand \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
    });
```

Here is the two different messages in json format received by Bot.

Address -Id in the first message Json is withoud `sip` and second message is with `sip` in Address-Id.

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2017-12-22T05:18:19.4976179Z",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "text": "hi",
    "address": {
        "id": //GUID
        "channelId": "skypeforbusiness",
        "user": {
            "id": "test@xyz.com",
            "name": "TestUserName"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "isGroup": true,
            "id": "NDJjOGUzNjcjc2lwOmJ1bWJsZWJlZUBiYW5uZXJ0ZWNoLm9ubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbQ=="
        },
        "bot": {
            "id": "sip:testbot@xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name": "sip:text@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        "serviceUrl": "https://webpoolbl20r04.infra.lync.com/platformservice/tgt-abcd/botframework"
    },
    "source": "skypeforbusiness",
    "agent": "botbuilder",
    "user": {
        "id": "test@xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "TestUserName"
    }
}


{
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2017-12-22T05:18:19.5601021Z",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "text": "hi",
    "address": {
        "id": "2",
       "channelId": "skypeforbusiness",
        "user": {
            "id": "sip:test@xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name": "TestUserName"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "isGroup": true,
            "id": "NDJjOGUzNjcjc2lwOmJ1bWJsZWJlZUBiYW5uZXJ0ZWNoLm9ubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbQ=="
        },
        "bot": {
            "id": "sip:testbot@xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name": "sip:testbot@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        "serviceUrl": "https://webpoolbl20r04.infra.lync.com/platformservice/tgt-3e269d45c99c53b8a53d91bd8610020f/botframework"
    },
    "source": "skypeforbusiness",
    "agent": "botbuilder",
    "user": {
        "id": "sip:test@xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "TestUserName"
    }
}
```

Comment: And? What's your problem?

Comment: This causes to problem that , As Bot receives two responces from the user, User also gets two replies. :(

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish... You could just check that field and remove the `sip:` or add the `sip:` in your code:

```
let id = idFromJson;
let prefix = "sip:";
if (id.includes(prefix)) {
   id = id.substring(3, id.length-1);
}
```

or

```
let id = idFromJson;
let prefix = "sip:";
if (!id.includes(prefix)) {
   id = prefix + id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JasonSowers. This is the same what I have tried...but this fails in case of windows sfb client, because , when User sends message from Windows client , bot receives only one respose , with sip: address.

Comment: Then why wouldn't either of these blocks of code work?  One would ensure you never have a prefix and the other would ensure you always have it.  I'm confused.